# Don't set .props.className of the React component?

Tags: reactjs

I've just updated to React 0.13.1 and am getting this warning:

```
Warning: Don't set .props.className of the React component. Instead, specify the correct value when initially creating the element. The element was created by ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you trying to modify `this.props.className` within your component? A component should not modify it's own props, they should be passed in by the parent.

Comment: Look at your third party modules, which might be doing something weird, or that code you wrote a few months ago, etc. There's not much we can add to the error without the specific code causing the problem.  And at the end you have "The element was created by ..." which tells you where to look.

Comment: That's what it sounds like, but I've checked the components (and there are a lot of them) that throw this warning and don't see anything immediately wrong. I'll keep playing with it and post here if I figure it out. Thanks.